# City Engine: Apply color ramp in points

Tags: cityengine

I have a shapefile of points loaded in city engine. I would like to apply a color ramp from red to blue accordingly to numeric values of a field of the attribute table. Should it do it by composing a rule? Field values range from -6 to 6 and I would like to use red colors for negative values, green for almost 0 and blue for positive values.

Comment: Could i somehow load the exact same symbology used in arcgis pro, in city engine?